# android gson listview populate

Tags: android, listview, gson

Hi i am learning android and i am trying to populate a list view.
i have fetched the data using gson.
my code is like this.
`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            Order[] values = gson.fromJson(s, Order[].class);`

and my arrrayadapter is like this

```
ArrayAdapter<Order> test1 = new ArrayAdapter<Order>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        list.setAdapter(test1);
```

i am sorry if this is a very stupid question.

Comment: what's you problem?gson went wrong?

Comment: please tell us what the problem is exactly

Comment: sorry i want to populate a list view but there is error dont know what is wrong.

Comment: whats the error? link the logcat, ah Array adapter takes only list of string as its 3rd parameter but values is array of Order objects

Comment: it is saying cannot resolve arrayadapter.

Comment: should i use .toString then?

Comment: post your Order's code, and tell us what you want to display in your list exactly

Comment: Order goes like this   public class Order {
    String id;
    String customer_id;
    String order_details;
}

Comment: so what do you want to show in your list view?

Comment: i am receiving a json file it contains many details(id,cuctomer id, order details). i want to show then individually in a list view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom adapter in order to show complex objects in a list, array adapter can only work with Strings it cannot work with complex objects, all an array adapter does is show whatever strings you pass to its constructor in a text view.